# Change img postion from Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an img and I need move it to the center of the page.
ّ
I use this code:

```
<image  height="300px" width="300px" src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'img/Rasd.jpeg')}}" >
```

[web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZqUa.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "the middle"? Have you searched for existing questions about centering, or vertically centering, images? There are a _lot_ of those.

Comment: I mean the center , yes I searched and can't found. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<center>
 <image  height="300px" width="300px" quality=95 mode='crop' src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'img/Rasd.jpeg')}}" >
</center>
```

add `<center>` this will be good and the img will be in the center.